# using a SOLID approach when handling web requests

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I am currently working on a Service Fabric solution where data gets sent from one sevice to the next service.

I am sending class with several properties. this class is a sort of datatransfer object. I want to use a solid approach to prevent the use of integers which lead to switch logic.

ie. I don't want this:

```
public void ExecuteFunctionForType(IntegerTypedClass myClass, IInterface myinterface)
{
    switch(myClass.typeInt)
    {
        case 1:
            // Do shizzle for type 1
            myinterface.execute1();
            break;
        case 2:
            // do shizzle for type 2
            myinterface.execute2();
            break;
    }
}
```

Instead i want to implement a SOLID approach. The one that comes to mind is shown below:

```
public abstract class AbstractTypedClass
{
    public abstract void ExecuteInheritedFunction(IInterface myinterface);
}

public class FirstTypedClass : AbstractTypedClass
{
    public override void ExecuteInheritedFunction(IInterface myinterface)
    {
        // do shizzle for the first typed class
        myinterface.execute1();
    }
}

public class SecondTypedClass : AbstractTypedClass
{
    public override void ExecuteInheritedFunction(IInterface myinterface)
    {
        // do shizzle for the second typed class
        myinterface.execute2();
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that the `AbstractTypedClass` and all it's children will have a dependency on the `IInterface`, which I don't want. This is due to the fact that it's a service fabric interface which brings a lot of other dependencies with it. 
I would prefer to have a solution where you can use the solid principle and not create a dependency on different libraries which will clutter up my solution

Things I can't use:

partial classes, because they need to be in the same assemvly

extension methods, because the default method gets called:

```
public static class TypedClassExtensions
{
    public static void executeExtension(this AbstractTypedClass request, IInterface myinterface)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public static void executeExtension(this FirstTypedClass request, IInterface myinterface)
    {
        myinterface.execute1();
    }
}

// when calling the code like so, the not implemented exception is thrown:
public void execute(AbstractTypedClass myclass, IInterface myinterface)
{
    myclass.executeExtension(myinterface);
}
```

Comment: Try the strategy pattern http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2009/11/22/applying-strategy-pattern-instead-of-using-switch-statements/

Comment: isn't the strategy what i just described? I am still stuck with the dependency to the interface if I use the strategy. Im looking for a way to remove the dependency

Comment: Show us your desired design output. It's doesn't have to work.. just to get idea. Because you said you don't want `interface` dependency.

Comment: You can avoid all this with pattern matching. We've come full circle to the point where you can avoid the strategy pattern by using switch. Besides - you can't add *all* the different methods you may want to call to all the classes

Comment: What you're looking for a design like [this](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91). What you should do however is inject `IInterface` using *Constructor Injection* instead of *Method Injection*. That allows you to have the same method signature for all 'request handlers'.

Answer (score 1):

In C# 7 you can use pattern matching to *avoid* using the strategy or visitor patterns. This results in cleaner code because you don't have to add the same methods to all concrete classes, or use double dispatch.

```
void ExecuteFunctionForType(AbstractTypedClass myClass, IInterface myinterface)
{
    switch(myClass)
    {
        case FirstTypedClass it1:
            // Do shizzle for type 1
            myinterface.execute1(it1.Prop1);
            break;
        case SecondTypedClass it2:
            // do shizzle for type 2
            myinterface.execute2(it2.Prop2);
            break;
    }
}
```

Assuming the interface and implementation look like this:

```
interface IInterface {void execute1(string input);void execute2(int input);}

class SomeClass:IInterface
{
    public void execute1(string input) => Console.WriteLine($"1 {input}");
    public void execute2(int    input) => Console.WriteLine($"2 {input}");
}
```

and the classes like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractTypedClass{    }

public class FirstTypedClass : AbstractTypedClass
{
    public string Prop1 =>"First";
}

public class SecondTypedClass : AbstractTypedClass
{
    public int Prop2 =>500;
}
```

You can call a different method per type with a switch statement that performs pattern matching on types. The following code :

```
var it=new SomeClass();
ExecuteFunctionForType(new FirstTypedClass(),it);
ExecuteFunctionForType(new SecondTypedClass(),it);
```

Will produce :

```
1 First
2 500
```

Pattern matching on type returns a strongly typed variable of the matching type. The members of each concrete type can be used without requiring a definition on an interface or abstract class.

Comment: I like this approach. Unfortunately we're not working with C# 7.0 yet

Answer (score 0):

Using SOLID principles I would think your approach would look like this:

The dependency inversion principle recommends that you only depend on the interfaces you need for the function.  So on your abstract class, I would simple make it generic and define the dependencies in the implementations of your abstract class.  This way if you can implement different versions in different assemblies and those assemblies wouldn't have needless dependencies.

```
// ------------ Assembly A -----------------
public abstract class AbstractTypedClass<T>
{
    public abstract void ExecuteInheritedFunction(T obj);
}

// ------------ Assembly B -----------------
IHugeDependency
{
    void execute1();
    ...more
}

public class FirstTypedClass : AbstractTypedClass<IHugeDependency>
{
    public override void ExecuteInheritedFunction(IHugeDependency obj)
    {
        // do shizzle for the first typed class
        obj.execute1();
    }
}

// ------------ Assembly C -----------------
ISmallerDependency
{
    void execute2();
}

public class SecondTypedClass : AbstractTypedClass<ISmallerDependency>
{
    public override void ExecuteInheritedFunction(ISmallerDependency obj)
    {
        // do shizzle for the second typed class
        obj.execute2();
    }
}
```

Using this approach Assembly B and C both have a dependency on A but B & C don't have a dependency on each other for no reason.